# Get collection of orders excluding cancelled order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, order-collection

I have got order collection with the following code:

```
$orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
```

Which is working fine. Problem is that it returns all types of orders including '**processing**', '**cancelled**' etc. I don't want the cancelled order in this collection.

I don't know how to exclude cancelled order in the above code.

Hope somebody helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just done this in Magento 2.4.
I found the statuses needed quotations to match. Here I filter orders by customer email and then orders of statuses - complete, processing and closed.

```
$orders = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory')->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $customer_email)->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array( 'complete','processing','closed')));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
$orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
$orders->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array(complete,processing)));
```

Status not in cancelled order will get into the collection.

am not sure about the status name **cancelled** make sure you use the exact one in the table sales_order table.

Comment: Call to undefined method Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection::addFieldToField()

Comment: sorry typo erro check now

Comment: I have checked it in db for status, its 'canceled' but still it is not working niether yours nor mine.

Comment: Will it returns collection

Comment: It is returning collection including all types of status

Comment: ok then instead of neq add nin

Comment: it is also not working bro. I think we are missing something here that I cannot found it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92037/discussion-between-prathap-gunasekaran-and-arshad-hussain).

Answer (score 3):

It isn't the best way to get collections in M2 using object manager. Use collection factorty for this purpose instead. Here's a short example:

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;

class SomeClass
{
    ...
    public function __construct(
        ...
        CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->collectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        ...
    }
    ...
     public function getOrders(){
         $orders = $this->collectionFactory()->create()
             ->addFieldToSelect('*')
             ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['neq' => 'cancelled']);
         return $orders;
    }
}
```

Comment: Magento is spelled using broken English (i.e. American). "Correct" spelling for the filter is "canceled" (even though the actual correct spelling **is** "cancelled", GARGH!!!)